# In javascript how to replace elements of an array to it's corresponding values in another object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping

I have the mapping of abbreviation and full name as follow:

```
object = {"TSLA":"TESLA INC.","GOOG":"GOOGLE INC.","APPL":"APPLE INC.","AMZN":"AMAZON CORPORATION", "MSFT":"MICROSOFT CORPORATION"}
```

as an output of function i get the following array:

```
array = ["AMZN","APPL"]
```

I want to display the values of the associated keys as follows:

```
output_array = ["AMAZON CORPORATION", "APPLE INC."]
```

Note that, the actual object has more `key: value` pairs

Using `IndexOf()` I can replace one value. However, I believe there must be a way of mapping the array elements to replace the values at once.

Since I am new to JS, I would appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

`array.map(abbr => object[abbr])` does the job; it iterates over the array rather than the object, which is more efficient as the object already is a lookup table with the right keys - you are right, there is no need to use `indexOf` which uses a linear search.

Comment: This is the answer i was looking for ! but why would someone give my question a negative point?